# 5 checkboxes in SQL-Generated HTML table, How to make them only apply for that row?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, checkbox

First post here, sorry for formatting.

So, I have a MySQL Database, that I am returning data from in the form of an HTML table.

Query follows.

```
select p.patient_id, pd.fname, pd.lname, p.drug, p.start_date, p.end_date, 
lo1.title as form, p.quantity, p.size, lo2.title as units, lo3.title as 
route, lo4.title as 'interval' from prescriptions as p
inner join patient_data pd on p.patient_id = pd.pid
inner join list_options lo1 on p.form = lo1.option_id
inner join list_options lo2 on p.unit = lo2.option_id
inner join list_options lo3 on p.route = lo3.option_id
inner join list_options lo4 on p.interval = lo4.option_id
where p.patient_id = '106'
and lo1.list_id = 'drug_form'
/* and lo1.option_id = '1' */
and lo2.list_id = 'drug_units'
/* and lo2.option_id = '1' */
and lo3.list_id = 'drug_route'
and lo4.list_id = 'drug_interval'
```

Which produces a table like this:
[SQL Table] -Redacted due to no reputation-

My Question is: I need to have 5 checkboxes per row returned in the HTML table (And yes, for the record, it is meant to be a dynamic query for entry of a different patient_id), but if I do a checkbox array using PHP, it returns the same five checkboxes to each row. How can we solve this? Please ask for further clarification, I understand I may need to provide more data.

UPDATE: Picture of intended HTML Table, returned by PHP
[HTML Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4WGE.png)

UPDATE 2: PHP Script: https://pastebin.com/8mWh1xfQ

Comment: there's no php/html, yet alone checkboxes here. That makes the question unclear and too broad. Edit: So, where/what is that? As per your: *"Please ask for further clarification, I understand I may need to provide more data."*

Comment: ...an array of arrays?  You're going to need to add an array object for each row.

Comment: Any way I can clarify, I can, and I apologize for my poor wording. As for An array for each row, let me post my code to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: PHP Posted for review

Comment: Which of the columns in the sql statement above correlate to the 5 checkboxes?

Comment: @pendo The checkboxes are going to be submitted through another form as extra data for whether or not a patient has taken their meds for the day, for now, please disregard

Comment: After re-reading, I think I know what you want to do.  When you submit the form, your PHP script that handles that request, doesn't know which row (patient) you came from, so it doesn't know which patient to associate the data with.

If you add a hidden field with the p.patient_id in it and your script looks for that value, that should do it.  Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @pendo That feels like it's on the right track, but the problem is, that multiple rows will have the same patient_id, due to some patients having multiple meds administered, and each med is a record all it's own.